# Create equal sized, random buckets, with no repetition to the row

Tags: sql, excel, random, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

Having some difficulty in a scheduling task.

Background: I have 100 members, 10 different sessions, and 10 different activities.
Rules:

1. Each member must do each activity only once.
2. Each activity must have the same number of members in each session.
3. The members must be with (at least mostly) different people in each session.
4. Each activity must be run in each session with 10 people per activity.

The expected outcome would be something like this:

| Person ID | Session ID | Activity ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | A |
| 2 | S1 | B |
| 3 | S1 | C |
| 1 | S2 | B |
| 2 | S2 | C |
| 3 | S2 | A |

In the above example, each activity in each session has only 1 participant, I have to lock that activity in that session out at 10 members.

I have tried a few different solutions in excel / SQL, but not able to meet all 3 rules. The hardest being keeping each activity/session slot to 10 people.

The closest solution I've had is the following.. its not pretty though:

```sql
SET STATISTICS TIME, io OFF

-- Create list of applicants
IF OBJECT_ID('process.Numbers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE process.Numbers

CREATE TABLE Numbers (ApplicantID INT, SessionID INT, GroupID INT)

DECLARE @i       INT,
        @Session INT,
        @Group   INT;

SELECT @i = 1;

SET NOCOUNT ON

WHILE @i <= 100
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Numbers (ApplicantID, SessionID) VALUES (@i, 1);

        SELECT @i = @i + 1;
    END;

-- Duplicate ApplicantID list for each different session
SELECT @Session = 1

WHILE @Session <= 10
    BEGIN
        IF @Session > 1
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO
                    Numbers (ApplicantID, SessionID)
                    SELECT ApplicantID, @Session FROM Numbers WHERE SessionID = 1
            END

        -- SELECT RANDOM TOP 10 AND SET AS GROUP ID

        SELECT @Group = 1

        WHILE @Group <= 10
            BEGIN
                WITH dups_check AS (   SELECT ApplicantID,
                                              GroupID,
                                              COUNT(*) AS vol
                                       FROM Numbers
                                       GROUP BY ApplicantID,
                                                GroupID),
                     cte AS (   SELECT TOP 10 *
                                FROM Numbers
                                WHERE numbers.GroupID IS NULL
                                      AND SessionID = @Session
                                      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                      FROM dups_check
                                                      WHERE Numbers.ApplicantID = dups_check.ApplicantID
                                                            AND dups_check.GroupID = @Group)
                                ORDER BY newid())
                UPDATE cte SET GroupID = @Group

                SELECT @Group = @Group + 1
            END

        SELECT @Session = @Session + 1
    END

SELECT * FROM Numbers

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

This code starts to fall over regularly in the higher session numbers when it tries to set an activity that the individual has already done.

Thanks!

Comment: (s1,a1)-> all members, .., (s10,a10)-> all members.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your code to Generate ApplicantID and SessionID rows and modified the last part to generate GroupID column using Ranking functions.

Below is the output of what I have tried:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME, io OFF

-- Create list of applicants
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Numbers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Numbers

CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers (ApplicantID INT, SessionID INT, GroupID INT)

DECLARE @i       INT,
    @Session INT,
    @Group   INT;

SELECT @i = 1;

SET NOCOUNT ON

WHILE @i <= 100
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Numbers (ApplicantID, SessionID) VALUES (@i, 1);

    SELECT @i = @i + 1;
END;

-- Duplicate ApplicantID list for each different session
 SELECT @Session = 1

WHILE @Session <= 10
BEGIN
    IF @Session > 1
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO
                Numbers (ApplicantID, SessionID)
                SELECT ApplicantID, @Session FROM Numbers WHERE SessionID = 1
        END

    SELECT @Session = @Session + 1
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF

drop table if exists #temp;

select ApplicantID, SessionID, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY applicantID ORDER BY applicantID) AS grp_row into #temp
from Numbers

update a
set a.GroupID = b.grp_row
from Numbers a
join #temp b on a.ApplicantID = b. ApplicantID and a.SessionID = b.SessionID
where a.GroupID is null
```

> 1. Each member must do each activity only once.

There are 100 applicants, and as an example, I am showing applicants 1 & 100. Here Each applicant is having each groupID only once.

[image]

> 2. Each activity must have the same number of members in each session.

There are 10 GroupID's and the number of applicants for each GroupID is the same (100).

[image]

> 3. The members must be with (at least mostly) different people in each session.

There are 100 applicants but I am taking the top 10 as an example. Here each sessionID has different applicants.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, this puts 50 people in an activity all together.  I've got to keep it to 10 people per activity per session.  Each activity must be running all the time. I've edited my original post to add this as a rule for easier visbility.